# VLC displays colors wrong

Tags: vlc

When I try to play a ["Heute Journal" Podcast file](http://podfiles.zdf.de/podcast/zdf_podcasts/111026_hjo_neu_p.mp4?2011-10-26+21-27) with VLC, I get colors that look like someone swapped U and V in YUV color system:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

I use VLC 1.1.12 on Oneiric

Comment: Please tell us, if you use an external monitor. Does it only happen when it is turned on? Maybe the model of your graphics card would also help.

Comment: I have a desktop computer which has one DVI monitor on a nvidia 9500 GT. The problem was actually with every video player (mplayer, dragon), so it was a graphics driver issue in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was only because I had the 173 driver installed, although my nvidia 9500 GT should use the current version. Switching to the current driver resolved this problem.