# VLC color problem in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, vlc, colors

I've got this color issue on my VLC player in Ubuntu 14.04. Unlike [other reported color problems on VLC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73199/vlc-displays-colors-wrong), colors are unevenly messed up on the screen. The attached pictures show how the lower left of the screen is stamped by (a yellowed version of) the end of a previous video I watched since I launched my computer, the end credits of Run Lola Run. In the top right hand part of the screen, the yellow is offset to the left. I've been having this problem for a while, and it happens about 2 times out of 3. How may I solve this?

[image: Yellow color offset 1].
[image: Yellow color offset 2]

Comment: I'm having the same issue myself, were you able to find a correction ?
In the meanwhile I purged the installation of VLC and moved to totem which
works perfectly fine. Might just stick with totem since it does everything I need it to. *I can only assume that the repo where I got VLC had a broken copy or somthing along the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you launch VLC press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. This should open the Preferences window for you. Now select the **Video** tab and under **Display** section *disable/de-select* **"Accelerated video output (Overlay)"**, this should fix the problem for you.
JFYI, this happens because you may not have the exact required driver for your graphics card which in some cases gets fixed with an update or else requires you to install one of the propriety drivers available by the vendor of your video card.

Answer (score 9):

This fixed my color playback related problems:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for Preferences → Video → Output
2. Change the output value to *X11 video output (XCB)*

Comment: This has helped me on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to get rid of washed out (pale) colors.

Comment: Bi-decade check-in: Ran into this issue on KDE neon (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) and this fix solved it as well.

Comment: 3. restart vlc (otherwise output value change won't take affect)

Answer (score 2):

I ad the same problem and solved by disabling "overlay" in basic video setting.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS, VLC 2.4.1 on ATI HD8600.

Comment: please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/530449/edit) you answer and explain that how to disable "overlay"?